# Tampermonkey script to check for a button and click it

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I am pretty new to creating scripts with tampermonkey and even after looking at several answers for the past few hours I still cant figure this one out.

I'm trying to make a script that checks for a button and when it appears for it to click it after about 2 seconds.

I am trying to search it by ID like this:

```
    var caseHide = document.getElementById("accept");
var checkTimer = setInterval(MyTimer, 1500);

function MyTimer() {
  if (caseHide.offsetParent === null)
    {
      return;
    }
  var eek = document.getElementById("accept");
  var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
  evt.initEvent("click", true, true);
  eek.dispatchEvent(evt);
}

checkTimer();
```

However when the button appears it's not being clicked.

I also must mention that this is a button that appears without a set interval because it's prompted by an alert, and as such I can't really say how often it will appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few thoughts.

The first `getElementById` will probably fail since that button likely does not exist yet.

Also, simply searching for `#accept` might not be enough to actually locate the element. It depends what your page looks like.

Here's what I do. In DevTools console, do this:

```
document.getElementById('accept').length
```

If it comes back undefined, then your css selector is not specific enough. You may have to *walk the tree* a bit more... something like:

```
document.querySelector('body #main .prevDiv #accept')
```

Do you know what I mean? Starting farther up the tree and walking down to the element.  If it doesn't work in DevTools, it won't work in TamperMonkey. In modern libraries like Angular/React/Svelte/etc, you might have more than one element with the same ID... so just specifying the single element might not find it.

Then, your function can look like this:

```
var checkTimer = setInterval(MyTimer, 1500);
checkTimer();

function MyTimer() {
   const eek = document.getElementById("accept");
   if (eek !== undefined){
      const evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
      evt.initEvent("click", true, true);
      eek.dispatchEvent(evt);
   }
}
```

References:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pr4LLrmDLLo

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SowaJlX1uKA

Comment: Thanks, this actually helped me shed a light on the issue, however I am getting another error now, the console keeps spitting out
Uncaught TypeError: eek is null
so I'm not sure how to un-null it

Comment: Try `if (eek !== undefined && eek !== null)`

Comment: Sorry  was busy with another project, however I can tell you that did resolve the issue!
Thank you very much for your help!